# continuous function and sin/cos

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, continuity

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $A = \{ a  \in \mathbb{R}: a = \pm \frac{p}{2^q}\pi, \ p,q \in \mathbb{N} \} $.
Given the functions $S: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $C: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

(i) Prove that if $f(a) = 0$, for all $a \in A$, so $f(a) = 0$, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

(ii) If $C$ and $S$ satisfy:

> (1) $C(0) = 1, S(\pi) = 0, \ C(\pi) = -1$
>
> (2)$ C(a - b) = C(a)C(b) + S(a)S(b)$
>
> (3) For $ 0 < a < \frac{\pi}{2} :$
>
> $$ 0 <C(a) < \frac{S(a)}{a} < \frac{1}{C(a)}$$

Prove that $C(a) = Cos(a)$ and $ S(a) = Sin(a)$, for all $a \in \mathbb{A}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

How to show that $C(x)$ and $S(x)$ are $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ respectively? What defines $sin$ and $cos$ functions?

About (i) I was trying to do it for a long time, but i couldn't. I would like to see a proof, if anyone can do it.

Comment: $\sin(\pi) = 0$, and not $1$.

Answer (score 0):

So, I can't prove one small part, but I'll outline what the solution is.

The crucial fact to see is that the set $A$ is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. just like $\mathbb{Q}$, for any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n \to x$. (Unfortunately, I can't prove this, but this is what is happening here)

Also, as the function $f$ is continuous, if $x_n \to x$, then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Now, as $x_n$ are in $A$, $f(x_n) = 0$. So, we get that $f(x) = 0$ too for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Here is the solution to the next part. (This assumes $C$ and $S$ are continuous)

Essentially, what we will do is show that $C(x) = \cos(x)$ for all $x\in A$, and hence use the $1^{st}$ part to show that this holds for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (similarly for $\sin(x)$ )

To do so, we will need the following results -

1. **$C^2(a)+S^2(a) = 1:$** Just set $a=b$ in the $2^{nd}$ property. This allows us to get the value of $S(x)$, if we have the value of $C(x)$, and vice versa.
2. **$C(2a) = 2C^2(a)-1$:** Just set $b=-a$, and use the $1^{st}$ result. This allows us to get the value of $C(\frac{x}{2^q})$ for all $q$ (by repeated application) if we have the value of $C(x)$.
3. **$C(-a)=C(a)$:** Set $a=0$, and use $S(0) = 0$ from result $1$. This will allow us to work with just one half of $\mathbb{R}$, and extend the results easily to the other half.

Using this, as you know $C(\pi)$, you can get $C(\frac{\pi}{2^q})$ for all $q$, and hence $S(\frac{\pi}{2^q})$. Now, using the addition formula for $C$, we can get $C(\frac{p}{2^q}\pi)$ for all $p,q$.

Eg. $C(\frac{3\pi}{2^q}) = C(\frac{4-1}{2^q}\pi) = C(\frac{4\pi}{2^q})C(\frac{\pi}{2^q}) + S(\frac{4\pi}{2^q})S(\frac{\pi}{2^q})$

Thus, as the initial values of $C$ and $S$ (at $0$ and $\pi$) are the same as $\cos$ and $\sin$, they are equal $\forall x\in A$ and hence $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I imagine this, but i have no idea how to show that $A$ is dense...

Comment: Do you have any idea for the other items?

Comment: Oh, I thought you had already done it. I just added a solution. If it's okay, then don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: sorry for not being clear and thanks for the solution, i understand now the way to prove it